# need help over python nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

i have a nested dic, i need loopover it to check if ip=x and cmd=y then take action xyz, how can i do that?

```
d={'ip': {'cmd': 'cmd_out'}, 'ip1': {'cmd1': 'cmd_out1'}}
```

i am able to get below:

```
for ip, cmd in d.items():
    print ip,cmd
```

out:-

```
ip {'cmd': 'cmd_out'}

ip1 {'cmd1': 'cmd_out1'}
```

what i want is something like below but not working:

```
for ip, cmd in d.items():

    if ip =='ip' and cmd=='cmd':

        print 'first IP' , ip  ### take action

    elif ip=='ip1' and cmd='cmd1':

        print "second ip" , ip   #####take action
```

i am new to python so simpler is better :)

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `d` dict, *ip* is a key and the value is another `dict` holding the value of `cmd`. In order to match both, you have to iterate it like:

```
d={'ip': {'cmd': 'cmd_out'}, 'ip1': {'cmd1': 'cmd_out1'}}
x, y = 'ip', 'cmd_out'  # Variable holding `ip` and `cmd`

for k, v in d.items():
    if k == x and v['cmd'] == y:
        print 'SUCCESS: We Found it'
```

Note: In case you don't know, *key* in `dict` are unique.